# Calculate rate of positive values by group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm working with a Pandas DataFrame having the following structure:

```
import pandas as pd
​
df = pd.DataFrame({'brand' : ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'], 
                   'target' : [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], 
                   'freq' : [5600, 220, 5700, 90, 5000, 100]})
​
print(df)
  brand  target  freq
0     A       0  5600
1     A       1   220
2     B       0  5700
3     B       1    90
4     C       0  5000
5     C       1   100
```

For each brand, I would like to calculate the ratio of positive targets, e.g. for brand A, the percentage of positive target is 220/(220+5600) = 0.0378.

My resulting DataFrame should look like the following:

```
  brand  target  freq   ratio
0     A       0  5600  0.0378
1     A       1   220  0.0378
2     B       0  5700  0.0156
3     B       1    90  0.0156
4     C       0  5000  0.0196
5     C       1   100  0.0196
```

I know that I should group my DataFrame by brand and then apply some function to each group (since I want to keep all rows in my final result I think I should use transform here). I tested a couple of things but without any success. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First sorting columns by `brand` and `target` for last `1` row per group and then divide in [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with lambda function:

```
df = df.sort_values(['brand','target'])
df['ratio'] = df.groupby('brand')['freq'].transform(lambda x: x.iat[-1] / x.sum())
print (df)
  brand  target  freq     ratio
0     A       0  5600  0.037801
1     A       1   220  0.037801
2     B       0  5700  0.015544
3     B       1    90  0.015544
4     C       0  5000  0.019608
5     C       1   100  0.019608
```

Or divide Series created by functions [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) and [`GroupBy.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['brand','target'])
g = df.groupby('brand')['freq']
df['ratio'] = g.transform('last').div(g.transform('sum'))
```